# Variable and expressions in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a ruby program where three numbers are entered and their sum is taken but if any numbers are the same they don't count toward the sum.
example (4,5,4) = 5
My problem is with my expressions. If i enter the same number I get multiple output for various combination. example enter 5,5,5 = 15,5,0

```
if a != b or c then
  puts a+b+c
elsif b != a or c then
  puts a+b+c
elsif c != a or b then 
  puts a+b+c
end

if a == b then
  puts c
elsif a == c then
  puts b
elsif b == c then
  puts a
end

if a == b and c then
  puts 0
elsif b == a and c then
  puts 0
elsif c == a and b then
  puts 0
end
```

Comment: This is how I would do: 1# Sort the *Array* 2# Iterate through the array, and for each element that appears only one (they will now be in runs-of-the-same-number) add it to a new array. #3 Sum the contents of the new array. (#1+#2 can be simplified with a `Enumerable#group_by` followed by `Enumerable.select` and #3 can be done with `Enumerable#reduce`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving it with two beautiful self explanatory one-liners

```
array = [a,b,c]

array = array.keep_if {|item| array.count(item) == 1 }
array.inject(0){|sum,item| sum + item}
```

-The first line creates an array with your parameters.
-The second line only keep the items whose count equals to 1 (remove the ones that appear more than one time), and store that on the array.
-The third line sums all the remaining elements.

Voilà, the ruby way :)

Comment: The third line can be written `array.inject(0, :+)`. This has two advantages IMO: 1) you can tell it's only adding, and not doing anything else, much more quickly 2) it has a cute emoticon.